# Build barcode list using values from different cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the best way to create barcode to over 5,000 unique items.
The guide line is that the barcode is built from the following: 
First four numbers- Product range (9000 in the sample case)
the next two digits, the product diameter (65)
next 3 digits my sph number and 3 more the cyl (cylinder number)

[image]
What will be my best option to do it efficiently.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one in cell **B1** and copy and fill down the column:
[image]

Supposing that your **product range** resides in **D1** and the diameter value in **D2**, and that your **sphere/cyl** values are in **column A** and the first value is in **A1**, then you can put this formula in **B1** and copy and fill down the column:

```
=CONCATENATE($D$1,$D$2,MID(A1,3,3),RIGHT(A1,3))
```